# Need sonar.lang.patterns for different languages?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, integration

Need sonar.lang.patterns for different languages like Java, .Net, Mainframe, Cobal, Psql, C, C++, C#, etc? while writing the analysis properties steps during Jenkins build. While Integrating SonarQube with Jenkins.
SonarQuve version 8.9.2 and Jenkins version 2.150.2

Comment: SonarQube 8.9.x will analyze all code it finds for which a plugin is installed. They now also by doe the language plugins.. You can find the corresponding extensions in the administration page.

Comment: Could you please tell me where exactly I can find the patterns for different languages on the Administration page? Since I am new to SonarQube.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube 8.9.x+ will analyze all code it finds for which a plugin is installed. They now also bundle all the language plugins the provide as part of each release.

You can find the corresponding extensions in the Administration page:
**Administration | Configuration | General Settings | Languages** (tab)
(`/admin/settings?category=languages`)

There's drop-down for installed/bundled languages and a section for each:
**General**
File Suffixes

I haven't tried it, but I suppose if you deleted a corresponding extension, then SQ should not discover any files corresponding to that language, if you wanted to skip one.

[Additional SonarQube Language](https://www.sonarqube.org/features/multi-languages/)s are provided as you pay for the product: 
**Community:** Java, C#, JavaScript, TypeScript, CloudFormation, Terraform, Kotlin, Ruby, Go, Scala, Flex, Python, PHP, HTML, CSS, XML and VB.NET 
**Developer:** C, C++, Obj-C, Swift, ABAP, T-SQL, PL/SQL 
**Enterprise:** Apex, COBOL, PL/I, RPG, VB6

If you add a custom language plugin from elsewhere, like the Marketplace (`/admin/marketplace?search=languages`) or a third-party site, it should end up as a separate tab, similar to "General" and "Languages" tab once installed.